# Changing Rows to Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have the following Data:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeLog (
    [User] NVARCHAR(6),
    [Event] NVARCHAR(3),
    [Time] DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO TimeLog VALUES
    (N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-15 00:31:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-16 20:10:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-21 14:59:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-22 01:01:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-22 10:46:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-23 00:58:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'IN','2015-04-23 14:50:00'),
    (N'Jibran',N'OUT','2015-04-24 01:37:00')
```

I want Each Event(For Every IN/OUT) to have a new Column with the User and Time as Rows.

Comment: provide your expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

use aggregate function with case

```
select user, max(case when Event='IN' then DATETIME end) as IN_time,
max(case when Event='OUT' then DATETIME end) as Out_time from t
group by user
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are having consecutive  `IN` and `OUT` events for each user, order by date correctly (not like in your example data exactly).

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to group the `IN` and `OUT` event in pairs, like this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Time])  + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Time]) % 2 AS [PairID]
      ,*
FROM [dbo].[TimeLog];
```

[image]

and then `PIVOT` to get the following result:

```
SELECT [User]
      ,[IN]
      ,[OUT] 
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Time]) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY [Time]) % 2 AS [PairID]
          ,*
    FROM [dbo].[TimeLog]
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Time]) FOR [Event] IN ([IN], [OUT])
) PVT
ORDER BY [PairID];
```

[image]

Note, I have changed one of your  `IN` event to `OUT` in order to sanitize the data. If this is not correct in your real example, I guess you can still use the logic above. For example, with your sample data, the maximum `IN` event is get and it has no `OUT` event:

[image]

You can play with the code, change the `MAX` to `MIN` or extend it with your business logic as well.